# Showing Error Cannot read property 'split' of null in microsoft edge, but working fine on chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm making a react-app,

I have stored userName on localStorage: `userName = Super Admin`

Here I need to take first letter of first name and first letter of second name to show on profile section like : `SA`

So I  split that first and take substring to get the first letter of the names.

**Its working fine on chrome but when I switch to edge Its showing Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

Here is my code:

```
class TopNavbar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    var user = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    console.log(user) //Super Admin 
    var components = user.split(" ");
    let firstNameLetter = components[0].substring(0, 1);
    let secondNameLetter = components[1].substring(0, 1);
    console.log(firstNameLetter)   //S
    console.log(secondNameLetter ) //A
    return (
      <>
        <Nav>
          <NavbarContainer>
            <NavLogoSection>
              <LogoText>FIX-BRIX</LogoText>
            </NavLogoSection>
              <UserNameSection>
                <UserNameText>
                  {firstNameLetter}
                  {secondNameLetter}
                </UserNameText>
              </UserNameSection>
          </NavbarContainer>
        </Nav>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default TopNavbar;
```

**NOTE**:

**Its working fine on google chrome, only showing error in microsoft edge**

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Probably you don't have that item in localstorage?

Comment: How can i use localstorage for both browsers in single login

Comment: well you need to add it there by hand or I don't know how you are adding it

Comment: I added to localstorage when user login. Here I didn't login in the edge. *So there is no items in localStorage* Thanks @DominikMatis for pointing out my mistake

Comment: Wrap it in an if statement checking if localstorage is set , if so, then read if not then ..whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have userName in localstorage on Microsoft Edge just yet. You can't assume that - you need to check if userName exists before trying to `.split()` it.

Consider:

```js
let firstNameLetter;
let secondNameLetter;

if (user) {
    var components = user.split(" ");
    firstNameLetter = components[0].substring(0, 1);
    secondNameLetter = components[1].substring(0, 1);
}
```